# How to get on island below Hardhaigh Palace?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

For one of quests in Xenoblade Chronicles 2, I need to get to island, which is placed directly below Hardhaigh Palace and its bridge. Yet, I see no way to get there safely. There are no elevators, ladders or any other convenient ways to go down, also no obstacles to prevent death from falling. How can I get down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fief of Forgetfulness.

To get there, go out of Alba Cavanich to the north, go east down some stairs, and jump down the cliff a bit until you come across a cave. That cave will take you to the location you need for this quest. Note: the cloud tide needs to be low for this to be accessible.

Comment: This is correct, but I will add that you have to take a long rest at the inn until the cloud level is below the median so that you can traverse the descending tunnel leading to the Fief.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a much more difficult path to get here, which is what I ended up doing because I didn't find the cave until later on and didn't really want to look up the proper entrance.

There are some buildings on the sides of the bridge that appear to be some sort of guardsman buildings or something. Anyway, you can jump up on the ledge of the those buildings and walk around them. If you jump up there and look down as you walk around, you'll see supports for the bridge that extend all the way down to the Fief of Forgetfullness. If you jump down and aim for those supports, you can actually land on the cross beams (while taking fall damage). From there, you can try to jump down to other cross beams until you can jump down to the ground.

Note: this path down will lead to death. Probably a lot of death. It's difficult, and since most players are not machines, it'll take a great many attempts to successfully jump down without dying to fall damage. If you're a pro at controlling your party leader (I am not a skilled jumper, so I died *a lot*), this may be a reasonable way to get down there without having to find the "proper" entrance. Then you can skip-travel back out of there.